# When is awarding bounties considered a misuse of the system?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

This question is in response to marmot's leaving of the site as discussed in the comments of [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/roles-and-actions-moderators/8369#8369). Comments are disabled there, so I ask this as a separate question.

In the comments [Stefan Kottwitz writes](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/roles-and-actions-moderators/8369#comment27071_8369):

> To the fact, that you are moving your points to others, thousands already: I saw the answers with the bounties and they are great and deserve appreciation. Why didn't you set the bounties earlier? Just to clarify then: you are now misusing the bounty system to move points massively. That can be considered as *gaming the system and reputation manipulation*.

I'm actually quite surprised to read this. Bounties to me serve two purposes: Either to raise attention to a question that doesn't have fully satisfying answers yet, or to show appreciation to a certain answer that you consider worth more that just a 10-points-upvote.

Users with a lower reputation score will certainly have to consider more carefully how much points they award as bounty and how often they do to not lose certain site privileges. But users with a 100k and above reputation clearly are able to award extra credits more generously.

While I still hope marmot changes his mind about leaving this site, *if* he finally decides to do so, I really appreciate that he wants to give back some of his points to others before doing so. I know answering questions shouldn't be about collecting points, but it's sometimes still a bit frustrating when you put a lot of effort or time into solving a problem and writing an answer (usually an old one) that pops up in the recent activity list for a few minutes and then forever vanishes in the depths of the site. It leaves you with that uneasy feeling no one cares about what you have written and the time you have spent on this. Receiving a bounty for such answers will certainly give you extra motivation.

So I really don't follow the insinuation that giving credits to others, especially in this case, could be considered a "reputation manipulation". I can't tell what criteria were considered to award the bounties, all of the answers seem TikZ-related, but it's not that bounties were given to random, low-quality answers or with the intent to push the reputation of certain users. To me the motivation just seemed to be "my credits will disappear after leaving the site, why not giving some of them back to the community before that happens?" That doesn't seem a bad intent to me at all.

@Stefan: Why do you consider the awarding a misuse of the bounty system in this case?
@All moderators: What awarding behavior in general is considered manipulative or a misuse of the system?

Comment: I was also surprised by that comment. Nevertheless, atleast I did not see any case of misuse of the system there. The bounties were awarded to some nice/possibly great Q&A.

Answer (score 8):

The main intention behind the bounties is to reward answers that have done something original. They include, but are not limited to, posts that have lead to new packages or libraries. It is true that most of the bounties were awarded to Ti*k*Z posts, and the reason is as simple as the fact that I am a bit more comfortable judging for those whether or not they are a major step forward than for other tags. Also I "earned" most of my points with Ti*k*Z related posts, so I just pass these points to other Ti*k*Z posts, and IMHO this does not "take away" anything from other tags. Altogether I do not understand at all why one should not be allowed to do that.

P.S. As for the "why now" question: true, the main motivation is that the points will decay once my account is deleted, which was scheduled for August 3. Why would it be "better" to let the points decay than to pass them to others? Let me mention that it is not the case that these are the first bounties I awarded. One bounty of 500 points I remember was to a user who wrote a stellar answer, but after she was done the OP changed the question. Unfortunately,  the user seems to have become inactive, yet the discussion why this happened is off-topic here. Nevertheless I'd like to reiterate that the purpose of all these bounties is to acknowledge *original* codes. And I feel that if there was a general agreement that originality (as opposed to just copying) is something valuable, many problems that surface here and there on meta could be avoided (and the current discussion would never have emerged). But this is just an opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Bounties are great! Showing appreciation to posts by bounties is great!

There are possible ways of [bounty fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169547/bounty-fraud-quid-pro-quo), such as

- shifting reputation to another account by bounties a lot
- circular bounties (moving rep point to another account, and that account moves it back, costs zero but a benefit may be visibilty and so gained rep/badges)

What that user now does, I just said it "*can be considered* as gaming the system and reputation manipulation". I didn't make a charge or an action, I gave a possible view point. So thanks for discussing it!

The only related situation I found is described in a comment by [whuber](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166924/whuber) (same link above):

> The only similar thing I remember anyone getting away with was a
>   high-rep user who, instead of quitting SE altogether, first shed all
>   his rep with a string of +500 bounties: but there was no quid pro quo
>   there (and I suspect the SE team nullified the effects anyway).

Sounds the same to me, so that user is not the first one having that idea.

The bounty system is very transparent, and reputation changes can also be seen. So, as you refer to that case, until now it's already about 18,000 reputation points the user transferred within days, growing, of about 145.000. Moving points massively, that are already "given up" by initiating the account deletion, doesn't look like normal use of the bounty system to me. In case that effect would be nullified, some users may be sad.

Comment: Could you please clarify why this `Until now it's already about 18,000 reputation points he transferred within days, growing. Moving points massively, that are already "given up" by initiating the account deletion, doesn't look like normal use of the bounty system to me.` doesn't look normal to you? Because to my understanding, bounties can be awarded to any answer that deserves it (upto the OP's discretion, unless they are explicitly committing any frauds). I do not agree with your view poitn (so a -1).

Comment: Moreover, you are contradicting your opinion here: `To the fact, that you are moving your points to others, thousands already: I saw the answers with the bounties and they are great and deserve appreciation.`  And for this: `Why didn't you set the bounties earlier?`, I think its upto the OP to decide when (atleast the model of SE allows that I suppose.

Comment: @Raaja To understand this, it is necessary to think in terms of cost and gain for financial capital such as a bank account. The goal is to increase the account, to cultivate it and to make it grow.
Capital represents reputation: the greater the capital, the greater the reputation. This capital is given by a central bank: here Stackechange. 
The principle of bonuses is to pay out of your own capital to increase someone else's reputation. So that's a cost... (to be continued)

Comment: @Raaja ... (suite) But since it has been announced that the capital will be burned in a kind of burning, the fact of giving points on its capital no longer costs anything because the goal is precisely to squander the capital and not to increase it. The very meaning of the bonus is no longer the same: you no longer pay on a capital that you want to make grow, you pay the others with a capital that no longer represents anything because it is destined to be destroyed.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: @AndréC I'm sorry but the reputation doesn't really mean anything :) (atleast to me). And to answer your point, if ones has wealth, its upto them to spend how they want it (legally ofcourse).

Comment: @Raaja For you, it means nothing, but for stackexchange it is important: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @Raaja I noticed that moving up to 145.000 reputation points might be a big effect of using the bounty system that may be unintended. So I expressed my concern. Mass-moving reputation points to make something out of it, is something different to adding some rewards to great answers without that other motivation.

Comment: @AndréC it is what it is ;)

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz I didnot understand your first point, could you clarify?

Comment: @Raaja It may not be the original plan of bounties to be used to transfer a huge amount of reputation. It may not look balanced. It can happen that if something is technically possible and allowed by rules and is then very much exploited, there can be more rules and limits, what we don't want. It's just a thought on an observation, you can have another opinion, that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz in all that case, why don't we remove the bounty option altogether? As an user of this site if I decide to award all my rep as bounty for well-deserved QAs, would you say its abnormal? Because that is what I understand from our discussion.

Comment: Nevertheless, the account deletion is initiated but not deleted yet. So as an user can play in the site without causing any disruptions dont they? And awarding bounties to a deserved question is neither a disruption nor gaming the system, I think. Feel free to refute it. I even see a badge in SE for rewarding bounties for other's questions.

Comment: And the badge reads: First bounty you manually award on another person's question. And please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work Therefore, I think it is a `SE` model and so far it's going good :)

Comment: @AndréC as for your analogy: as much as SE worries about the rep, it also gives way to spend it as far as it in performed in accordance to their rules. So I am hightly doubting that they dont want us to spend our rep. If they did, there would not be any option for providing bounties.

Comment: @Raaja We won't remove the option, that's because bounties are great. I agree with you. Spreading tens of thousands of points after initiating self deletion is just another level. I guess there's a reason why there's a limit of 3 active bounties per user at the same time. That takes the speed out of reputation movement. No need to change anything. I just answered your question with some explanation of my thoughts.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I also expressed opinions. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Raaja I'm afraid I've been misunderstood. Either I express myself badly or the machine translation is not correct. I didn't say that SE doesn't want us to give bonuses (it's intended to), I say that bonuses have a cost: they take away reputation points (from capital). They only have meaning if the bonus costs capital to the person who gives it. It is this cost that gives value to the bonus. A bonus that costs nothing is worthless.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: @AndréC All points have been earned and are well deserved. It's like giving away what is not needed anymore. I'm fine with that, it's more like taking a step back and trying to see it from another perspective.

Comment: @AndréC no problems :)

Comment: @AndréC When writing the question, I also thought about that money analogy. If you are a billionaire and about to die, why not spending all your money before it happens? If you think of reputation as money, then it shouldn't matter what you do with your points before you leave the site. The value of the reputation/money is still the same, even if not to you because you won't need it anymore. But it's not that the reputation loses value for the community. I still see some responsibility for the one to award the points to use it wisely and in a way that doesn't cause harm to the community.

Comment: @siracusa Don't take it too serious ;-) just reputation score is also kind of a game and virtual success. A billionaire leaving the game but (instead of just leaving) moving the wealth of points to selected others, is, possibly, a non-balanced modification. I saw it being used wisely though.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I am not talking about the choice of answers to which bounties are attributed, they are all highly voted answers.   I'm talking about the meaning, the meaning of the bonuses. A bonus is natively designed to have a cost that can go up to a loss of privilege. Here, these bonuses have no cost since the goal is to destroy these points. This approach is therefore not in line with the very spirit in which these bonuses were designed.

Comment: @AndréC The bounty system serves two purposes: boost an question that has not received enough attention and reward answer that are especially good. The cost is an irrelevant part of it, (and especially for high rep users the cost is essentially zero). Long before you arrived we had a user who *regularly* reduced their reputation dramatically by awarding bounties in this way. The bounties were always well deserved (as are the bounties we're discussing here). They simply didn't care for reputation and so decided to "spend" it. This is no different from that.

Comment: @AndréC Atop what Alan already explained, I would like to add a point. First of all, I would not agree with your inference here: `Here, these bonuses have no cost since the goal is to destroy these points. This approach is therefore not in line with the very spirit in which these bonuses were designed.`.  The points/rep/capital -- irrespective of whether they have value or not -- an OP can burn it as they like (as far as it is inline with the SE guidelines I.e., no fraud is being made, atleast that is what I understand).

Comment: Moreover, neither you nor me, have any rights to tell another OP on how they can spend their reps. This part is solely upto their discretion. Also, in this specific scenario, the OP who is spending their "own rep/capital" is giving it as bounty to well deserved QAs (which imo is one of the main motivations behind the bounty). Moreover, I really do not understand when you say it's not inline with the spirit of bounty. It's their bounty/rep and let them do whatever they want, as far they do it legally.

Comment: @AndréC as a final point, one fine day if I decide to leave TEXSE, I will have more time to spend to find good QAs (more than what I'm aware of). Once I do find them, I would be more than happy to distribute my points to the well-deserved QAs. And, I prefer to call it charity (because I am learning a lot from here) instead of defaming it.

Comment: @Raaja If you leave stackexchange, all reputation and bonus points you have distributed will be removed from those who received them. It takes a very high reputation for this mechanism not to work.

Comment: @AlanMunn You are talking about the purpose of bonuses, I am talking about their very principle of operation, which is based on that of a bank account since the help page states this: `All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.` https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: @AndréC I have no idea why that is relevant. You were complaining that the bounties under discussion aren't inline with the "spirit" of the bounty. That has nothing to do with the bank accounts model, but seems to be a moral judgment about how they are being used in this case.

Comment: @AndréC as I understood bounties, it will not be reversed except my up votes. Nevertheless, if that is the case (which I highly doubt) I will not delete my profile ;)

Comment: @AlanMunn I note that the functioning of bonuses is that of a payment, a bank transfer. This is at a cost as indicated in the help page. If this payment no longer has any cost, it is no longer a payment: it is the creation of money.

Comment: @Raaja read this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/bounties-from-deleted-accounts-should-still-be-awarded-al-least-the-indicator/89614#89614

Comment: @Raaja https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86028/446930

Comment: @AndréC I dont understand what you want me to see there, sorry for that. But the answers clearly reads that: `The bounty will just be moved to (owned) by the Community user and will be awarded automatically at the end of the period as they normally would.`. Therefore, to summarise, deleting an account will not reverse the effect of bounty.

Comment: @AndréC I think you are confusing several variables by creating analogy with real-world funds. First, the rep is still earned by someone, who offers it to some nice QA because it's great. So once awarded the rep belongs to the one who got awarded. Then, if the one who awarded the rep decides to leave the site, that doesn't mean it's no longer a payment. It is still a payment from the past. After all, we are living in a causal system ;) just because the source of the past action is no longer present, the present reaction will not become void. It still happened. I hope it's clear:)

Comment: @Raaja I may misunderstand, but it seems to me that this is not what the moderator says in his comment here:  Grace Note♦ Apr 5 '11 at 16:15 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85954/bounties-from-deleted-accounts-should-still-be-awarded-al-least-the-indicator/89614#comment211447_86028

Comment: @AndréC I think the mod was expressing their personal opinion. Moreover, kindly refer to recent answers/updates. Because, imo it's better to look at recent rather than old updates (please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). Let's not go back-and-forth and let us avoid redundancy, because I have already added a much recent link for a discussion regarding this subject. Nevertheless, I'm again referring the same discussion for your convenience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97229/discussion-between-andrec-and-raaja).

Comment: @Raaja As no staff moderator reacted to my comments, I have just clearly asked the question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332919/446930

Comment: @AndréC thanks for the link, hope we will get a clarity. I think you should also add the point: what will happen to bounties that were awarded by deleted users.

Comment: @AndréC I hope the answers and comments were made clear to you in MSE :)

Comment: @Raaja Not so fast. One moderator acknowledged that she did not know and therefore had not been officially informed and the other, like you, stated that she did not make it an official response from the Staff. If it were that simple, the Staff would have responded officially. So far, everyone has only given a personal opinion.

Comment: @AndréC What do you mean by not officially responded? I don't get it, you got a response from `animuson` who is both a mod and a staff for SE.